LaTeX equations formatting problem
I am trying to build the following equation in LaTeX without the text between the two sections.

However, I can't do it. I would be super grateful for help.
\begin{align*}
    \max_{e, s} \hat{U}(b, \tau)= & u(w-\tau-s)+\beta[\hat{\pi}(e) u(w-\tau+(1+r) s) \\
    & +(1-\hat{\pi}(e)) u(b+(1+r) s)-e]
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
    & \text{s.t.} \quad \hat{\pi}^{\prime}(e)[u(c_e)-u(c_u)]-1=0 \hfill (\text{IC}_e) \\
    & \phantom{\text{s.t.}} -u^{\prime}(c_0)+\beta(1+r)\{\hat{\pi}(e)[u^{\prime}(c_e)-u^{\prime}(c_u)]+u^{\prime}(c_u)\}=0 \hfill (\text{IC}_s).
\end{align*}

I'm not that familiar with LaTeX, so I'll just list all the packages I use here. Even if I don't know exactly which ones are relevant here.
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue, pdfstartview=FitH, pdfpagelayout=OneColumn]{hyperref}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow,bigdelim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=small,labelfont=bf,labelsep=space,format=plain]{caption}
\usepackage[authoryear, longnamesfirst]{natbib}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{float}


The language on this site is English, please.

You possibly want something like the following.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newlength{\stlen}
\AtBeginDocument{\settowidth{\stlen}{s.t.\quad$$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
& \hspace*{-\stlen}
  \hat{U}(b, \tau)=
  \max_{e, s}
  \begin{aligned}[t]
    & u(w-\tau-s)+\beta[\hat{\pi}(e) u(w-\tau+(1+r) s) \\
    &\quad +(1-\hat{\pi}(e)) u(b+(1+r) s)-e]
  \end{aligned}
\\
\text{s.t.}\quad
& \hat{\pi}'(e)[u(c_e)-u(c_u)]-1=0 \tag{IC$_e$} \\
& {-}u'(c_0)+\beta(1+r)\{\hat{\pi}(e)[u'(c_e)-u'(c_u)]+u'(c_u)\}=0. \tag{IC$_s$}
\end{align*}

\end{document}


As regards your preamble, I warn you from taking someone else's and add to it. You end up loading lots of useless packages and possible instability.
For instance, tabularx appears twice (which is a hint to you trying to add to someone else's preamble) and hyperref should go last.
Clean it up and only add those packages that are necessary for the document you're writing.
